# How do I make a radio button only able to select 1 option per group?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have 5 radio button groups. I am wanting the user to only be able to select one part in each radio group. My first group works fine and is only selecting one part, however the other groups when I select something instead of the selected button moving from 1 it selects another part.

The code I have for this is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Checkboxes and radio buttons assignment 4 </title>
</head>
<body>

<form name=form1>

<h2>Complete the following</h2>
<hr>
Tick the box if you have the following:
<h2>History of Hereditary Disease </h2>
Heart <input type="checkbox" name=chkHeart value="Heart"> <br><br>
Asthma <input type="checkbox" name=chkAsthma value="Asthma"> 

<br><br>
Arthritis <input type="checkbox" name=chkArthritis 

value="Arthritis">
<br>
<hr>

Select the button that describes you:

<h2>Exercise</h2>
<input type="radio" name=radspeed CHECKED onclick="return 

Frequently_onclick(0)" value="Frequently"> Frequently
<input type="radio" name=radspeed onclick="return Average_onclick(1)" value="Average"> Average
<input type="radio" name=radspeed onclick="return Seldom_onclick(2)" value="Seldom"> Seldom
<br>
<hr>

<h2>Diet</h2>
<input type="radio" name=Low Fat CHECKED onclick="return LowFat_onclick(0)" value="Low Fat"> Low Fat
<input type="radio" name=Average onclick="return AverageFat_onclick(1)" value="Average"> Average
<input type="radio" name=High Fat onclick="return HighFat_onclick(2)" value="High Fat"> High Fat
<br>
<hr>

<h2>Alcohol</h2>
<input type="radio" name=LightAlcohol CHECKED onclick="return LightAlcohol_onclick(0)" value="Light"> Light
<input type="radio" name=MediumAlcohol onclick="return MediumAlcohol_onclick(1)" value="Medium"> Medium
<input type="radio" name=HeavyAlcholo onclick="return HeavyAlcohol_onclick(2)" value="Heavy"> Heavy
<br>
<hr>

<h2>Smoking</h2>
<input type="radio" name=NonSmoker CHECKED onclick="return NonSmoker_onclick(0)" value="Non-Smoker"> Non-Smoker
<input type="radio" name=LightSmoker onclick="return LightSmoker_onclick(1)" value="Light"> Light
<input type="radio" name=HeavySmoker onclick="return HeavySmoker_onclick(2)" value="Heavy"> Heavy
<br>
<hr>

<h2>General Health</h2>
<input type="radio" name=GoodHealth CHECKED onclick="return GoodHealth_onclick(0)" value="Good"> Good
<input type="radio" name=AverageHealth onclick="return AverageHealth_onclick(1)" value="Average"> Average
<input type="radio" name=PoorHealth onclick="return PoorHealth_onclick(2)" value="Poor"> Poor
<br>
<br>
<hr>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: give the same name to each radio button within a single group and differenciate it with different ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set same name for specific group.
Your first group have a same name and another group with different name.
You can check it [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)

Comment: Thanks thats a massive help.